# How to mask a specific column using AWS DMS?

Tags: etl, aws-dms

Requirement is that we have some PII information in some of our columns, we want to mask these columns and store it in our warehouse for analytics purpose.

I know there is an option to add-column and apply transformations, but I can't add new column for some business reasons.

Is there a way to mask the column directly without creating the new column in the warehouse?

I have checked if there is any modify-column option [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html), but no clue so far